# Problema al iniciar simulador Android con react native

Tags: android-studio, react-native

Hace 3 dias que tengo el mismo problema, instalo una nueva aplicacion react native:

> react-native init proyecto

Luego en el android studio inicio el AVD, configuro un mobile, lo inicio y levantao el proyecto

> react-native run-android

Ahora el problema se da cuando apago la computadora y cuando vuelvo encender (a las horas o dia siguiente y ahi al querer ejecutar el proyecto primero me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si vuelvo a ejecutar tira:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Antes de iniciar tu proyecto con ***react-native run-android*** cierra todas las terminales que tengas abiertas, y luego intenta de nuevo, y comenta si te funcionó

Comment: Cuando estas probando en el emulador react-native corre un "server" donde se ejecuta la app que luego se muestra en el emulador, asegurate que se este ejecutando correctamente. Por lo que dice el error no lo esta encontrando y podria deberse a eso. A mi me paso lo mismo con el simulador de iOS